# boost::assign::map_list_of value of enum type

Tags: c++, boost

Why does boost::assign::map_list_of yield an_enum is not of class type error?
e.g.

```
exp.aggregates = (
                       boost::assign::map_list_of
                       ("a",static_cast<an_enum>(3)),               
                       ("b",static_cast<an_enum>(4)),
                       ("c",static_cast<an_enum>(0))
                 ).operator ltr_and_enum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change it to somthing like this and see what happens?

```
map<string, an_enum> myMap = boost::assign::map_list_of
                   ("a",static_cast<an_enum>(3)),               
                   ("b",static_cast<an_enum>(4)),
                   ("c",static_cast<an_enum>(0)));

exp.aggregates = myMap.operator ltr_and_enum();
```

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b4a364831ac3555bf651082cd7991e1b-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: So it works. Then anybody could explain when it is possible to receive such an error (from the 1st post)?

Comment: I believe map_list_of needs to be put into a map, while you want it to work like just  list_of, look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#map_list_of